# Type-punning (GCC) - incrementing a pointer parameter on stack

Tags: pointers, gcc, casting

OK, I understand that the GCC 4.x warning "dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules" is no joke and I should clean up my code.

I have code which compiles und runs fine with GCC 3.x, and would be very happy if it would do so with GCC 4.x, too. Assume I want to have the assembled code as short as possible: the function gets passed a pointer and should write some data to there. My original code uses the pointer directly on the stack (without a copy) and increments it there (note that I don't want to pass the incremented value back to the caller). You may think also of passing parameters by register - then any copy would be overhead.

So this was my "ideal" code:

```
void foo(void *pdataout) {
    for (int i=16; i--;)
        *(*reinterpret_cast<BYTE**>(&pdataout))++ = 255;
}
```

I tried some variant (note that the address-operator must be applied to 'pdataout' before any type-cast):

```
void foo(void *pdataout) {
    BYTE *pdo = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(*reinterpret_cast<BYTE**>(&pdataout));

    for (int i=16; i--;)
        *pdo++ = 255;
}
```

and also this:

```
void foo(void *pdataout) {
    BYTE *pdo = *reinterpret_cast<BYTE**>(&pdataout);

    for (int i=16; i--;)
        *pdo++ = 255;
}
```

Nothing pleases GCC 4.x... This last one does - but, it uses a copy of the parameter which I don't like. Is there a way to do this without the copy? I have no idea how to tell it the compiler :-(

```
void foo(void *pdataout) {
    BYTE *pdo = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(pdataout);

    for (int i=16; i--;)
        *pdo++ = 255;
}
```

Comment: I really do not recognize why copying the pointer (and incrementing only the copy) can solve any problem - or is the code still dangerous but the GCC does not detect it? Compare first with last code snippet. I would be glad if someone can explain!

Comment: It seems the problem can be simplified to `float test = 0.0f;
if (!*(long*)&test) {};
long *ptest = (long*)&test;
if (!*ptest) {};`: the first `&test` line causes a warning, the others not. Why? And are the last 2 lines safe?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand now, despite there is no more warning by GCC, using the indirection via an additional variable **is not safe!**

For me (as `union` is not usable), the only real solution is to use the `-fno-strict-aliasing` compiler option. Only with that, GCC is aware that pointers of different type to the same memory address can refer to the same variable.

[This article](http://thiemonagel.de/2010/01/no-strict-aliasing/) finally helped me to understand strict-aliasing.